# Pillow python : Improve script performance

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, gevent

I have a simple script that gets the image size from a list of images URL but it's way too slow when the list is too big (ex: 120 URLs, it can take 10 seconds to run)

```
def get_image_size(url):
    data = requests.get(url).content
    try:
        im = Image.open(BytesIO(data))
        size = im.size
    except:
        size = False
    return size

list_images = ['https://example.com/img.png', ...]
for img in list_images:
    get_image_size(img)
```

I already tried Gevent which can make me save 50% of the processing time but it's not enough. I'd like to know if there is another option to make this script run faster?

The final goal is to get the 5 biggest images of the data set.

Comment: Go multithreaded with `joblib` and do a bunch in parallel.

Comment: Remember, accessing things a long way away via HTTP is high latency - maybe 1s to initiate the transfer and 100ms of transfer time. If you incur all those 1s delays sequentially they will add up to a long delay with many files, if you do all the hanging around in parallel then the delays will mask each other out by overlapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of [grequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests) (requests and gevent) and instead of using Pillow to get the image size, you can identify the image size from the HTTP headers:

[image]

Usually performance depends on the network connection/server speed and image size:

```
import grequests


def downloadImages(images):
    result = {}
    rs = (grequests.get(t) for t in images)
    downloads = grequests.map(rs, size=len(images))

    for download in downloads:
        _status = 200 == download.status_code
        _url = download.url

        if _status:
            for k, v in download.headers.items():
                if k.lower() == 'content-length':
                    result[_url] = v
                    continue
        else:
            result[_url] = -1
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    urls = [
        'https://b.tile.openstreetmap.org/12/2075/1409.png',
        'https://b.tile.openstreetmap.org/12/2075/1410.png',
        'https://b.tile.openstreetmap.org/12/2075/1411.png',
        'https://b.tile.openstreetmap.org/12/2075/1412.png'
    ]

    sizes = downloadImages(urls)
    pprint.pprint(sizes)
```

Returns:

```
{'https://b.tile.openstreetmap.org/12/2075/1409.png': '40472',
 'https://b.tile.openstreetmap.org/12/2075/1410.png': '38267',
 'https://b.tile.openstreetmap.org/12/2075/1411.png': '36338',
 'https://b.tile.openstreetmap.org/12/2075/1412.png': '30467'}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try this out